# JSON/RPC/Client.pm Missing - Fedora 17

Tags: json, perl, rpc

I want to run a JSON request using Zabbix API, but I get the following error:

```
Can't locate JSON/RPC/Client.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 
/usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl                 
/usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at ./test.perl line 6.
```

I'am using Fedora 17 and don't find the package named: `libjson-rpc-perl`. I've already installed the following packages:

```
perl-CGI-Application-Plugin-JSON.noarch                                          1.02-   5.fc17                                                            fedora                      
perl-Catalyst-View-JSON.noarch                                                   0.30-5.fc17                                                            fedora                      
perl-JSON-Any.noarch                                                             1.29-1.fc17                                                            fedora                      
perl-JSON-Any-tests.noarch                                                       1.29-1.fc17                                                            fedora                      
perl-JSON-PP.noarch                                                              2.27200-3.fc17                                                         fedora                      
perl-JSON-Path.noarch                                                            0.101-2.fc17                                                           fedora                      
perl-JSON-RPC-Daemon.noarch                                                      1.03-2.fc17                                                            updates                     
perl-JSON-RPC-legacy.noarch                                                      1.01-2.fc17                                                            fedora                      
perl-JSON-RPC-legacy-server.noarch                                               1.01-2.fc17                                                            fedora                      
perl-JSON-Util.noarch                                                            0.05-3.fc17                                                            fedora                      
perl-JSON-XS.x86_64                                                              1:2.32-1.fc17                                                          fedora                      
perl-JSON-XS-tests.x86_64                                                        1:2.32-1.fc17                                                          fedora                      
perl-JSON-tests.noarch                                                           2.53-4.fc17                                                            fedora                      
perl-MooseX-Types-JSON.noarch                                                    0.02-7.fc17                                                            fedora                      
perl-MooseX-Types-JSON-tests.noarch                                              0.02-7.fc17                                                            fedora                      
perl-Test-CPAN-Meta-JSON.noarch                                                  0.13-1.fc17                                                            fedora                      
perl-Test-JSON.noarch                                                            0.11-6.fc17                                                            fedora                      
perl-Test-JSON-tests.noarch                                                      0.11-6.fc17                                                            fedora
```

I don't know what to do now ? Can you please advice ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON::RPC::Client was provided by an older version of [JSON-RPC](https://metacpan.org/release/JSON-RPC).  Version 1.00 of JSON-RPC broke backwards compatibility with previous releases and no longer includes that module.  You'd have to install the older version to get this code to work (or update the code to use the new API).  You can get [JSON-RPC 0.96 (the last compatible version) here](https://metacpan.org/release/MAKAMAKA/JSON-RPC-0.96/).

You can [install the old version in a private location](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq8.html#How-do-I-keep-my-own-module-library-directory-) just for this code.

Comment: I get it form here : [link](http://blog.zabbix.com/getting-started-with-zabbix-api/1381/)

Answer (score 2):

in your code :

```
use JSON::RPC::Legacy::Client;
```

and also change:

```
my $client     = new JSON::RPC::Legacy::Client;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~dmaki/JSON-RPC-1.03/lib/JSON/RPC.pm) to install JSON::RPC. It's usually simple procedure. There is also a tool somewhere that converts CPAN distributions into rpms, but you might find cpan easier to handle without additional conversion step.

Comment: I've installed CPAN, then downloaded JSON::RPC package, but still doesn't work :

Comment: No reference at the JSON/RPC/Client.pm during the installation.

Answer (score 1):

In general, in Fedora (and anywhere else in the Red Hat world), if you don't know which package contains the module you need, you can run:

```
% yum install 'perl(Module::Name)'
```

In this case, that would be:

```
% yum install 'perl(JSON::RPC::Client)'
```